# Mod rewrite with parameters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In fact, I am working on a small PHP script and I want to redirect this :

```
http://localhost/app-[NUMBERS].html?code=[LETTERS AND NUMBERS]
```

to this:

```
http://localhost/app.php?id=[NUMBERS]&code=[LETTERS AND NUMBERS]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^app-([0-9]+)\.html /app.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This captures the numeric portion of the request, and converts it to the **id** query string parameter. The `QSA` flag deals with any existing parameters, and passes them through untouched.

e.g.

```
http://scratch.bagheera/app-12345.html?code=ABC123
```

->

```
http://localhost/app.php?id=12345&code=ABC123
```